# Using textfields and a grid in another page

Tags: java, eclipse, gridview, grid, vaadin

I need to know how to take info from the user in one page using a label and textfield and displaying that in a grid in another page.

For example, Im getting the name of the user and displaying their name in following page in a grid. I'm using eclipse and working with vaadin, if that helps.

Comment: How do you switch to the grid-page? Usually you have a button on the first page and onClick you read the value of the textfield and then pass it to the constructor of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

if what you need is an info from connected user, I suggest you to set the User object as Session Attribute.

IE:

```
User connectedUser = new User();
VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute(User.class, connectedUser);
```

Then, if you need to pick this information, you just have to call

```
User currentUser = (User) VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute(User.class);
```

Then, you can pick with all your getter all the required infos, like

```
String username = currentUser.getUsername();
```

In my opinion the best approach is to set the user attribute after his login, so you can have it everywhere you need to pick it from any class of your Vaadin application.

Hope this helps.
Bye